# Apache Tika detect is returning inconsistent result

Tags: java, file-type, apache-tika

I am trying to find out the content type of a file using apache tika.

mean while i found this inconsistent behaviour.

```
final Tika tika = new Tika();

String fileType = tika.detect(uploadedInputStream);
System.out.println(fileType);
String newFileType = tika.detect(uploadedInputStream);
System.out.println(newFileType);
```

the above code is giving me out put as

```
application/pdf
application/octet-stream
```

I am expecting the output as `application/pdf` in both cases.

Can anyone explain why it is happening like this? how can I get the intended result?

Comment: Apache Tika has a few requirements about what kind of InputStream it can detect from without changing the state of it. What happens if you try wrapping yours in a TikaInputStream?

Comment: Thanks a lot, this one helped me.  Could you please tel me more about, why it was happening with normal InputStream and how TikaInputStream Solved it

Comment: When Tika is done detecting, it needs to rewind the stream for the next user (eg a second detection). If your stream claims to support rewinding but doesn't actually, then those bytes are gone and you're stuffed....

Comment: In addition to @Gagravarr comment: if Tika founds that InputStream doesn't support rewind (i. e. returns `false` for `InputStream#isMarkSupported`) Tika wraps it to `BufferedInputStream` to do actual detection and consumes some kilobytes of original stream (up to 64k if use `Tika#detect` or `MimeTypes#detect`). `BufferedInputStream` is, of course, lost after detection process.

Comment: So to add to @KonstantinGribov 's comment: if you use Tika, you need to pass in a properly wrapped (resettable) stream - and *use the same stream* for the rest of your logic as well. Otherwise the rest of the processing will be incorrect/inconsistent because part of the original stream is already consumed, and there is no way to "recover" those already-read (lost) bytes other than re-reading them from the wrapped stream (which would internally handle the buffered-to-actual read transition gracefully).

Answer (score 2):

When I wrapped InputStream in TikaInputStream  as suggested in the comments, I could see that the problem is solved

```
    final Tika tika = new Tika();
    TikaInputStream tikaInputStream = TikaInputStream.get(uploadedInputStream);
    String fileType = tika.detect(tikaInputStream);
    System.out.println(fileType);
    final Tika newTika = new Tika();
    String newFileType = newTika.detect(tikaInputStream);
    System.out.println(newFileType);
```

OutPut:

```
     application/pdf
     application/pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to detect content type using tika it consumes your entire input stream and it will be empty after once. So the moment you are trying the second time by giving the same input stream you will be seeing application/octet-stream (an Unknown binary) because your stream is empty.

```
Tika tika = new Tika();
// preserve your stream as an instance and reuse it
TikaInputStream tikaInputStream = TikaInputStream.get(inputStream);
String fileType = tika.detect(tikaInputStream);
System.out.println(fileType);
final Tika newTika = new Tika();
String newFileType = newTika.detect(tikaInputStream);
System.out.println(newFileType);
```

You can also make duplicate copies of your source input stream to preserve it.